# Jira/Javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, jira

brand new to javascript and im trying to do an if statement with the condition :

```
if (issue.issueTypeObject.name == "Specials")
```

If it equals specials then do this:

```
 <!-- @@Formula:
if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10007")==null)
  return null;
else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
   return 0;
else
return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
 -->
```

else do this

```
    <!-- @@Formula:
if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10002")==null)
  return null;
else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
   return 0;
Else
return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24)
 -->
```

and i just cant seem to get it right

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by html comments all i know is that the above codes work and when i join them like rgthree stated below: it still does not work.. so my only guess is that this bit is not working correctly --> issue.issueTypeObject.name == 'Specials'

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you seeing? You can try using the script debugger in Chrome or Firefox. Alternatively, you could output the value of the string to console like this:

```
console.log(issue.issueTypeObject.name);
```

One thing you could try is a case insensitive string comparison

```
 if (issue.issueTypeObject.name.trim().toUpperCase() === "SPECIALS")
```

Comment: not getting any errors as i cant see the log due to it being hosted on an external server i only have admin through Jira. have tried the case sensitive response without any luck:( how can i do it through chrome console?

Comment: Here are some instructions from Google on how to set break points using Chrome dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging#debug You might also have some luck trying some tutorials on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLqswS6r-e0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Jira formulas and we won't be able to tell what your `issue` object actually contains. However, assuming `issue.issueTypeObject.name` is a valid string as you have it and `issue.get` is a function (and those date getters return `Date` objects), I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
<!-- @@Formula:
if (issue.issueTypeObject.name == "Specials") {

  if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10007")==null)
    return null;
  else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
    return 0;
  else
    return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);

} else {

  if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10002")==null)
    return null;
  else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
    return 0;
  else
    return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);

}
-->
```

Comment: thank you for your help atleast i know that my if statements are correct! makes more sense with less {} hehe. now to just get this thing working..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- @@Formula:
if (issue.get("issuetype") == "Specials") {

  if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10007")==null)
    return null;
  else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
    return 0;
  else
    return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10007").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);

} else {

  if (issue.get("resolutiondate") == null || issue.get("customfield_10002")==null)
    return null;
  else if ((issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24) <1)
    return 0;
  else
    return (issue.get("resolutiondate").getTime() - issue.get("customfield_10002").getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);

}
-->
```